# Interactive Drush Script

Tags: 8, drush

I would like to write an interactive Drush script that *potentially* makes a change to all pages of a website.  Let's say we would would like to change "Foo" to "Baz" on each page.  We want to review each changed page before it is saved.  The code would look something like this:

```
foreach(website as node) {
  if node->body->value contains "Foo" {
    change "Foo" to "Baz" and display the changed version of body for the user
    Prompt User: Commit change? Yes or No
    if "Yes", save the node
    }
}
```

It appears Drush is buffering output so that I can not interact with the user in this way.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drush has built-in functions to handle I/O.

If you're using Drush <9.x, there's the procedural [`drush_confirm()`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/8.x/includes/drush.inc#L397) that will prompt a user for a response to a given message. If you're using 9.x+, any custom command class extending the `DrushCommands` class will have access to the `$this->io()->confirm` method which does the same thing with Symphony's CLI components.

See the latest Drush docs for [more info on I/O](https://docs.drush.org/en/master/io/).

Comment: Thank you @Shawn Conn!! Greg

Answer (score 2):

I found the following [3 ways to prompt for user input in Drush](https://www.webomelette.com/drush-command-get-user-input) which contains a solution.

```
if (drush_confirm('Print \'Hello world\' to the screen?')) {
  drush_print('Hello world!');
}
else {
  drush_user_abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On New drush versions, can you use the below, in a both command file and as drush script e.g. `drush scr /path/to/script.php`

```php
use Drush\Exceptions\UserAbortException;

// Script to setup the round theme.
$do_run_if_no_input = FALSE;
$answer = $this->io()->confirm('Do you want to continue?', $do_run_if_no_input);
if (!$answer) {
    throw new UserAbortException("Command cancelled.");
}
$this->io()->writeln('Continuing...');
```

@see https://github.com/drush-ops/example-drush-extension/blob/master/ExampleCommands.php